# How can I add my current location to Firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 application, I'm able to see my current location on the map, but how can I add the location (longtitude and latitude) to Firebase?

```
initMap(): Promise<any> {

    this.mapInitialised = true;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {


        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        //let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713744, -74.009056);

        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
        resolve(true);
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
          this.clearMarkers();
          let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
          let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
          let distanceToYou = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
            event.latLng,
            position,
            'miles'
          ).toFixed(2);
          this.geocodeLatLng(event.latLng,geocoder,infowindow,distanceToYou);
        });
      });

    });

  }
```

I'm able to get the current position of me and if I double click the map I can see the distance between me and the marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But since double clicking a map zooms it, i'll use `press`. But it would be better if you set a button on a info window with a "save location" text or something like this to call the saving function.

**YOUR HTML**

```
<div #mapID (press)="saveLocation()">
```

**YOUR .TS**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

public lat;
public long;

initMap(): Promise<any> {
  this.mapInitialised = true;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.long = position.coords.longitude;
      // YOUR CODE CONTINUES HERE...
    });
  });
});

saveLocation(){
  firebase.database().ref('PATH/YOU/WANT/TO/SAVE').update({
    lat: this.lat,
    long: this.long
  }).then(res =>{
    // THE LOCATION IS SAVED, DO YOUR STUFF
  })
}
```

Like this you can save you location, use `update()` instead of `set()` so you don't subscribe other data.

If you want to retrieve that data just use `firebase.database().ref('PATH/YOU'VE/SAVED').once('value', snapshot =>{ // CODE });`

Hope it helps